# No permission to access web site

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

My setup:

```
ubuntu 22.04
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server 

I created /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mysite.conf:

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@xxxxxxxx.com
   ServerName test.xxxxxxxx.com
   DocumentRoot /home/test/deploy/current
   <Directory /home/test/deploy/current>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I disabled the built-in 000-default.conf as follows:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

And verified that it was no longer in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

And enabled the virtual host:

```
sudo a2ensite test.mysite.conf
```

And verified that it was now in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

I verified that the configuration is fine:

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

And restarted the apache server:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Here is a list of the permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x root root  /
drwxr-xr-x root root  home
drwxr-x--- test test  test
drwxr-xr-x test test  deploy
drwxrwxr-x test test  current
-rw-rw-r-- test test  index.html
```

This is hosted on AWS, so I also went to AWS, and verified that the security group's inbound rules, allowing connecting from my home IP address (I have a fixed IP address). I also don't have the firewall enabled on the server.

But when I do http://test.xxxxxxxx.com

I get the following message in my browser:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at test.xxxxxxxx.com Port 80
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the permissions for `/home`, `/home/test`, `/home/test/deploy` and `/home/test/deploy/current`?

Comment: @vidarlo Isn't the only folder that matters /home/test/deploy/current? I have the permissions listed in my question.

Comment: No, all parent folder permissions also matter. Please show the output of `namei -l /home/test/deploy/current`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I edited the question, to add all the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions in `/home/test/` are too restricted.

```
drwxr-x--- test test  test
```

Nobody but `test` is allowed to enter this directory, so Apache can't read it.

`/home/` is not the right place to place a webroot anyway. Use `/var/www` instead.

Comment: Adding a read permission solved it. drwxr-xr-x test test test. Organizing in folders, allows me to have multiple vhosts, and disabling /var/www might provide more security.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Organize in folders all you want, but not in `/home`. Use `/var/www/`, `/srv/`, `/opt/www` or whatever, but `/home` is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I still don't see an explanation why organizing under /home is a bad idea.

Comment: Basically because that means a security problem will give Apache access to your users home directories.

Comment: @vidarlo If a security problem, allows a hacker to access the /home folder, wouldn't the /var/www folder also be exposed?

Comment: Yes, `/var/www`  would obviously be. But not your home directory. Thats kinda the point.